# Compare documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I am trying to get all documents which have same mobile type. I couldn't find a relevant question and am currently stuck.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/sessions/session/1' \
     -d '{"useragent": "1121212","mobile": "android", "browser": "mozilla", "device": "computer", "service-code": "1112"}'
```

EDIT -

I need `Elasticsearch` equivalent of following -

```
SELECT * FROM session s1, session s2 
where s1.device == s2.device
```

Comment: I tried something this- curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/sessions/session/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": "doc[\"device\"].value == doc[\"device\"].value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
 which obviously doesn't work. I am not sure how to refer to two different documents.

Comment: I don't want to give you the solution as it looks like you haven't really tried that much but I'll point you to the good direction : You'll need to run a filtered term query. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html.

Comment: Thanks! I had read the document already. Unfortunately, couldn't find the approach. :(

Comment: Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is simple grouping docs on a field via self-join.

The similar notion of grouping can be achieved by [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) in elasticsearch. Although this aggregation returns only the group level metrics like count, sum etc. It does not return the individual records.

However, there is another aggregation which can be applied as a sub-aggregation to the terms aggregation, [top-hits aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html).

> The top_hits aggregator can effectively be used to group result sets
>   by certain fields via a bucket aggregator. One or more bucket
>   aggregators determines by which properties a result set get sliced
>   into.

Options

- `from` - The offset from the first result you want to fetch.
- `size` - The maximum number of top matching hits to return per bucket. By default the top three matching hits are returned.
- `sort` - How the top matching hits should be sorted. By default the hits are sorted by the score of the main query.

Here is a sample query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top-mobiles": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "device"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_device_hits": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```